# KML trying to reference I gif file that is inside of a jar

Tags: kml

I have a GroundOverlay with an gif file for the image.
When I'm in the Eclipse debuger it will load the image fine.

But when we build our project so that it all gets embedded into a jar file Google Earh does not know how to find that gif anymore. Does the gif file need to be outside of the jar or is there a way to reference a file that is inside of the jar?

Thank you very much!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't provide a lot of information about how you reference the file in the KMZ. You may want to check this article for more information about how to reference files within a KMZ:
https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmzarchives

Comment: thank you that sounds like what I might need. I may ask further questions later